# Protobuf performance in Swift

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers

I am getting performance worse than I expected during protobuf deserialization in Swift.

My .proto file is the following:

```
message BufVariant {
     string Chrom = 1;
     int32 Pos = 2;
     string Ref = 3;
     string Alt = 4;
     string Type = 5;
     int32 Length = 6;
     string AnnoType = 7;
     string Consequence = 8;
     float ConsScore = 9;
     string ConsDetail = 10;
     string oAA = 11;
     string nAA = 12;
     string GeneID = 13;
     string FeatureID = 14;
     string GeneName = 15;
     string CCDS = 16;
     string SIFTcat = 17;
     float SIFTval = 18;
     string PolyPhenCat = 19;
     float PolyPhenVal = 20;
}

message BufGene {
    repeated BufVariant bufvariants = 1;
}
```

Each BufVariant has 20 attributes (which I believe after tag 15 the storage takes 2 bytes, but isn't my main concern).  I am trying to deserialize about 100,000 BufVariants, which are contained in a single BufGene.

```
// deserialize the BufGene into a [BufVariant] array                               
let decodedBlob = try BufGene(serializedData: serVariants)
```

That line takes 11.1 seconds to execute with 100,000 BufVariants.   Is this reasonable?  Is there some way to speed this up in Swift?

Comment: Is this in release mode with optimizations turned on?

Answer (score 0):

My protobuf setup was fine.   But per @Alexander's comment, once I did the build in release mode with -O optimization (for speed) turned on, the parsing time went from 11.1 seconds to 0.56 seconds (about a 20x increase).

I also changed the .proto file so the BufVariant was nested in the BufGene, and that further dropped the time down to 0.37 seconds.

Comment: Yes, Swift relies _very_ heavily on optimisation.